# How to identify annotations of invocated jax-rs method in resteasy filter within quarkus reactive context

Tags: java, quarkus, resteasy, quarkus-reactive

Moving from `quarkus-resteasy` to `quarkus-resteasy-reactive` I have encountered an issue within one `jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter`.

Previously, the code was trying to identify which `http method` a `java method` was `annotated` with, but this doesn't work anymore as `resourceInfo` doesn't provide these `annotations`.

```
    @Inject
    ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext contextRequest, ContainerResponseContext contextResponse) {
        
        Method resourceMethod = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
        if (resourceMethod != null && resourceMethod.isAnnotationPresent(POST.class)) {

            // do something 
        }

    }
```

Is there any other way to identify the annotations of the invoked rest endpoint within this filter context?

Quarkus version: 3.6.1

Comment: ResourceInfo just returns a method, so you can should be able to get the annotations.

Comment: It would be great to see declared class level annotations and a minimal reproductible example. I assume you are using tricks (e.g. `@PreMatching` annotation and / or inheritance). BTW  Does `HttpMethod.GET.equalsIgnoreCase(contextRequest.getMethod())` condition enough for you?